# django - How to change existing code to ModelForm instance

Tags: python, django, modelform

New to Django and this is my first web application.

I'm having trouble with django's ModelForm feature and I wanted to know:

How do I modify my code so that I can create an instance of ModelForm, and specifically, how can I extract the form data to upload to the backend? I will need to reference this instance at a later time to re-populate the same data in an `update_profile` view but the updation can only happen once the user is logged in (after signup and profile creation).

For the editing section, do I use `pk=some_record.pk`? Very confused, any help is appreciated.

The model I'm working with `CustomerDetail` has a foreign key field `customer` which references the `Customer` model:

```
class CustomerDetail(models.Model):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex = r'^\d{10}$', message = "Invalid format! E.g. 4088385778")
    date_regex = RegexValidator(regex = r'^(\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})$', message = "Invalid format! E.g. 05/16/91")

    customer = models.OneToOneField(Customer,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    primary_key=True,)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.CharField(validators = [date_regex], max_length = 10, blank = True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    home_phone = models.CharField(validators = [phone_regex], max_length = 10, blank = True)
    work_phone = models.CharField(validators = [phone_regex], max_length = 10, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.customer)
```

Here is a snippet of `views.py`:

```
def create_profile(request):
if request.POST:
    address = request.POST['address']
    date_of_birth = request.POST['date_of_birth']
    company = request.POST['company']
    home_phone = request.POST['home_phone']
    work_phone = request.POST['work_phone']

    custprofdata = CustomerDetail(address = address, date_of_birth = date_of_birth, company = company, home_phone = home_phone, work_phone = work_phone)
    custprofdata.save()

    output = {'address': address, 'dateofbirth': date_of_birth, 'company': company, 'homephone': home_phone, 'workphone': work_phone}

    return render(request, 'newuser/profile_created.html', output)
else:
    return redirect(create_profile)
```

And here is a snippet of the form part of the respective `create_profile.html`:

```
<form action = "{% url 'create_profile' %}" class="create_profile" role="form" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address" class="col-md-3 control-label">Address</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="777 Park St" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="date-of-birth" class="col-md-3 control-label">Date Of Birth</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="09/12/82" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="company" class="col-md-3 control-label">Company</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" placeholder="Oracle">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="home-phone" class="col-md-3 control-label">Home Phone</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="home_phone" placeholder="4082992788">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="work-phone" class="col-md-3 control-label">Work Phone</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="work_phone" placeholder="6690039955">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
        <button type = "create" class="btn btn-success" form = "create_profile"> Submit </button>
    </div>
    </div>              
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a basic ModelForm is just a matter of the following:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import CustomerDetail

class CustomerDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerDetail
        fields = ['address', 'date_of_birth', 'company', 'home_phone', 'work_phone',]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example

But I suggest you also switch to using a Class Based View (CBV) - the CreateView will do the same as your existing view with much less code, with an implicit ModelForm (which you can customise by providing your own ModelForm class with `form_class = YourFormClass` if you want).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview

https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/

Answer (score 1):

After creating CustomerDetailForm as @John Carter said, you might want to change your view.py to the following

```py
def create_profile(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = CustomerDetailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ## save data in database ##
            return render(request, 'newuser/profile_created.html', {form:form})
    else:
        return redirect(create_profile)
```

Comment: to save the data should i put `form.save()`?

Comment: yes but not on form. It should be same as your old view.py